# Spring - runtime choice between two implementations

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Let's say I have a `HigherLevelBean` that depends on `LittleService`. The `LittleService` is an interface with two implementations.

There is no static or semi-static way to tell which of the two implementations should be used, it's all dynamic (session scoped, in fact). When request from this user comes in use the `LegacyLittleService`, and for requests from that other user use `NewShinyLittleService`.

The services are not going to be that small. They will have their own dependencies that will need to be injected and they will probably come from two different application contexts. Think about using one app over two different schemas/data models.

How can I achieve this kind of runtime dynamic? Ideally with annotation-driven configuration. What are my options, their pros and cons?

Comment: I don't understand something - Do you know at start up which dependency you need?

Comment: @Avi - no, and it's not static. At the same time I may be serving requests from two different users each using different implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply have a factory, where both services are injected:

```
@Component
public class LittleServiceFactory {
    @Autowired
    private LegacyLittleService legacy;

    @Autowired
    private NewShinyLittleService newShiny;

    @Autowired
    private TheSessionScopedBean theSessionScopedBean;

    public LittleService get() {
        if (theSessionScopedBean.shouldUseLegacy()) {
            return legacy;
        }
        else {
            return newShiny;
        }
    }
}
```

Now inject this factory anywhere you want, and call get() to access the appropriate LittleService instance.

Comment: Not bad, but two issues: 1. If I have 10 service types, I need to have 10 such factories. 2. I'm not sure if I want those services to live in the same application context. It gets interesting here, boils down to parent being aware of and choosing between two child contexts.

Comment: You get the idea. You could also implement a proxy which implements LittleService, and delegates to Legacy of NewShiny based on the session scoped bean. You wouldn't even need the factory. But the idea is basically the same: you inject the two implementations, and choose the right one based on the session scoped bean.

Comment: Hi. Please look into this question and help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29765870/passing-session-factories-from-one-service-to-another     I'm trying the same method to achieve it.